# Android geolocation API > 23

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to geolocation the user.
It works in an activity but I can't make it work in a fragment (here MapsFragment).

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        /***********************Geolocalisation de l'utilisateur***********************/
        /***********DROITS*********/
        // Assume thisActivity is the current activity
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
        Log.e("DROITS :", String.valueOf(permissionCheck));

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }

        permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
        Log.e("DROITS :", String.valueOf(permissionCheck));
        /**************************/

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        ArrayList<String> names = (ArrayList<String>) locationManager.getProviders(true); //Récupère les providers

        //On ajoute des critère pour trouver le meilleur provider (indicateur de position)
        Criteria critere = new Criteria();
        critere.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);//On demande une position précise
        critere.setAltitudeRequired(false);         // Est-ce que le fournisseur doit être capable de donner une altitude ?
        critere.setBearingRequired(true);           // Est-ce que le fournisseur doit être capable de donner une direction ?
        critere.setCostAllowed(false);              // Est-ce que le fournisseur peut être payant ?
        critere.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH); //On accepte d'utiliser un provider a haute consommation électrique(GPS)
        critere.setSpeedRequired(false); // Est-ce que le fournisseur doit être capable de donner une vitesse ?


        List<String> providers = locationManager.getAllProviders(); //Liste des fournisseurs qui correspondent
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(critere, true); //Liste des fournisseurs qui correspondent




        int y = 0;
        Log.e("Provider n°", "fdfgdfgdf");

        Log.e("Provider n°", String.valueOf(providers.size()));



        if(bestProvider == null)
        {
            Log.e("Best Provider","NULL");
        }
        else{
            Log.e("Best Provider", bestProvider);
        }

        Location positionNow = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider); //Objet location qui contient la position de l'utilisateur
        Log.e("Position user now", "Lat:"+String.valueOf(positionNow.getLatitude()));


    }
}
```

I tried to use the "context" but it doesn't work.
For example: Context doesn't know "shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale".
I recovered the context with: "Context mainContext = getActivity (). getApplicationContext ();"

### I'm starting on Android, thank you in advance for your help

EDIT :
I've tried that. But I get an error:"android. support. v4. app. FragmentActivity. getApplicationContext ()' on a null object reference".

```html
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private int REQUEST_LOCATION;
private List<Marqueur> tousLesMarqueurs = new ArrayList<>();

public MapsFragment() {

    /*******/
    getUserPosition();
    getAllMark();
    /*******/
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
    final SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
  
    //Add Markers

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}


public void getAllMark() {

    //API REST Request
    }


public void getUserPosition()
{
    /**************AUTORISATION***************/
    Context mainContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    // Assume thisActivity is the current activity
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mainContext,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
    Log.e("DROITS :", String.valueOf(permissionCheck));

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mainContext,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) mainContext,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mainContext,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_LOCATION);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }

    permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mainContext,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
    Log.e("DROITS :", String.valueOf(permissionCheck));
    /*****************************/
    /*

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mainContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    ArrayList<String> names = (ArrayList<String>) locationManager.getProviders(true); //Récupère les providers

    //On ajoute des critère pour trouver le meilleur provider (indicateur de position)
    Criteria critere = new Criteria();
    critere.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);//On demande une position précise
    critere.setAltitudeRequired(false);         // Est-ce que le fournisseur doit être capable de donner une altitude ?
    critere.setBearingRequired(true);           // Est-ce que le fournisseur doit être capable de donner une direction ?
    critere.setCostAllowed(false);              // Est-ce que le fournisseur peut être payant ?
    critere.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH); //On accepte d'utiliser un provider a haute consommation électrique(GPS)
    critere.setSpeedRequired(false); // Est-ce que le fournisseur doit être capable de donner une vitesse ?


    List<String> providers = locationManager.getAllProviders(); //Liste des fournisseurs qui correspondent
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(critere, true); //Liste des fournisseurs qui correspondent




    int y = 0;
    Log.e("Provider n°", "fdfgdfgdf");

    Log.e("Provider n°", String.valueOf(providers.size()));



    if(bestProvider == null)
    {
        Log.e("Best Provider","NULL");
    }
    else{
        Log.e("Best Provider", bestProvider);
    }

    Location positionNow = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider); //Objet location qui contient la position de l'utilisateur
    Log.e("Position user now", "Lat:"+String.valueOf(positionNow.getLatitude()));*/
}


}//Fin Class
```

EDIT 2 :
Thank you very much for your help!
I have no errors but obviously the IF is not activated. Am I in the right block ?
"

```html
public void getUserPosition() {

        /*****************************/
        Context mainContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        // Assume thisActivity is the current activity
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mainContext,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
        Log.e("DROITS :", String.valueOf(permissionCheck));

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mainContext,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) mainContext,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mainContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                ArrayList<String> names = (ArrayList<String>) locationManager.getProviders(true); //Récupère les providers

                //On ajoute des critère pour trouver le meilleur provider (indicateur de position)
                Criteria critere = new Criteria();
                critere.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);//On demande une position précise
                critere.setAltitudeRequired(false);         // Est-ce que le fournisseur doit être capable de donner une altitude ?
                critere.setBearingRequired(true);           // Est-ce que le fournisseur doit être capable de donner une direction ?
                critere.setCostAllowed(false);              // Est-ce que le fournisseur peut être payant ?
                critere.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH); //On accepte d'utiliser un provider a haute consommation électrique(GPS)
                critere.setSpeedRequired(false); // Est-ce que le fournisseur doit être capable de donner une vitesse ?


                List<String> providers = locationManager.getAllProviders(); //Liste des fournisseurs qui correspondent
                String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(critere, true); //Liste des fournisseurs qui correspondent




                int y = 0;
                Log.e("Provider n°", "fdfgdfgdf");

                Log.e("Provider n°", String.valueOf(providers.size()));



                if(bestProvider == null)
                {
                    Log.e("Best Provider","NULL");
                }
                else{
                    Log.e("Best Provider", bestProvider);
                }

                Location positionNow = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider); //Objet location qui contient la position de l'utilisateur
                Log.e("Position user now", "Lat:"+String.valueOf(positionNow.getLatitude()));


            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                Log.e("PAS LE DROIT!", "GPS INTERDIT !");

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mainContext,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        REQUEST_LOCATION);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }

        permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mainContext,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
        Log.e("DROITS :", String.valueOf(permissionCheck));
        /*****************************/


    }

}//Fin Class
```

"

Comment: Where are you calling `Context mainContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();` in fragment? exactly in which function?

Comment: I edited my first message.
I call it in the constructor of the Maps fragment.
In the getUserPosition function.

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment, you can typeCast your context to your activity.

```
((MainActivity)context) or ((MainActivity)getActivity)
```

and you can proceed normally.

Comment: Do you have an example, please?

Comment: example for what?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your explanation.

Comment: what problem exactly you are facing?

Comment: Please, Read my Edit.

Comment: Okay. So the problem is that you are trying to access the activity/context too early. Move your code written in constructor to onCreateView.

Comment: The application crash with the error: "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference"

Comment: You are getting null location from the user. Write the code where you are accessing the location in  the block when the permission is granted.

Comment: Look at the Edit 2. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: no. For that I would suggest you ask a different question on how to handle run time permissions. Here is a good link on how to do that.
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/